# How to mark selected items as checked in laravel multiselect dropdown

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, multi-select

I am using [this](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select)  multiselect dropdown plugin . I can get all the ids of the selected items in the dropdown during the store method. However during the edit method when ever i am trying to load the entity that has multiple values , i am unable to mark the items as checked in the dropdown.

so for example - 
Suppose I am working with Contacts. Each contact can belong to many categories. There is a belongsToMany relationship between the contacts and the categories. Whenever I am adding a new contact (and if the user has selected many categories) i get the id of all the categories and assign it to the contact. Now when I am trying to load the contact again, i have to display the list of categories that were selected for this contact - which i have ben unable to do so till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I accomplish multi-selects in Laravel 4:

```
<?= Form::select(
    'category_ids[]',
    App::make('Category')->lists('name', 'id'),
    $contact->categories()->select('categories.id AS id')->lists('id'),
    [
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'multiple'
    ]
)?>
```

The resulting select markup looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" name="category_ids[]">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">category 1</option>
    <option value="2">category 2</option>
</select>
```

And then, when you update, you'll need to add this line after validating your model:

```
$contact->categories()->sync(Input::get('category_ids'));
```

Use this in both your create and edit forms. In your `create` action, 
`$contact->categories()` will be empty, so the select will not be populated, but in the `edit` action, you will get the properly selected values.

*Edit:* In order to share the form like this, you'll need to pass in a new instance of the `contact` model in your `create` action like so:

```
public function create()
{
    $contact = App::make('Contact');
    return View::make('contact.create', concat('contact'));
}
```

In your shared form, $contact will always be available even if it's not yet persisted.

Comment: Thanks Travis. It really helped me a lot. marking your answer as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Travis answers really helped me a lot. Hence I am marking this as the correct answer. However there were some updates that I had to do . Following is what I had to do ..

```
            @if(isset($contact))
            <?= Form::select(
                'category_ids[]',
                Category::lists("name", "id"),
                $contact->categories()->select('categories.id AS id')->lists('id'),
                [
                    'class' => 'form-control multiselect',
                    'multiple'
                ]
            )?>
        @else
            {{ Form::select("category_ids[]", Category::lists("name", "id"), Input::old("category_id"), array( "class" => "form-control multiselect" , "multiple" => "multiple" )) }}
        @endif
```

I am using the same form for the create and edit operations , so in the create form , it was throwing me an error on the contact->categories line which is true because in the create method the contact is null. Hence the check.

Comment: Glad I could help, Gagan. Just wanted to comment and say that you don't need that conditional in your form. Just pass in a new instance of the contact model to your view in your create action.

This way, the contact variable is set and you can use the example I gave without any conditionals. I edited my answer to account for it.